# Best practice with Azure Functions implementation and trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have a discussion with some colleagues of mine about the Azure Functions. I'm giving you a bit of context.

I have created an Azure Functions responsible for communicating the accounting system. In this function I have all I need related to the accounting. So, if you want to use my functions, you know in this one you find everything. I think it is easy to manage also because everything is in one solution. Probably, if I have to update a model or a function, other functions or classes are effected.

[image: List of Azure Functions]

For this reason, I have in this function different triggers (HTTP, Servicebus, Timer...). I think an Azure Function is container and each function in it is a "micro" service and it implements SOLID principles by nature. Then, I can say my implementation is correct.

My colleagues said it is not good practice to mix different type of triggers in the same Azure Function.

What is the best practice? Is there any (official) recommendation or advice for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay to use different type of triggers in the same Azure Function. But you need to consider that functions within a function app share resources.

Here is the general best practices for your reference.

[General best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#general-best-practices)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Can you explain me what you mean with "you need to consider that functions within a function app share resources"?

Comment: @Enrico For example, memory is shared.